# read text file (colon separated words) and get a dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

hay i been trying to read from a text file then convert it into a dictionary. 
this what i have in the text file

```
("Tom","1"):("Tom", "x", "R")
("Tom","_"):("Matt", "_", "L")
("Matt","1"):("Matt", "1", "L")
("Matt","x"):("Dan", "1", "R")
("Matt","_"):("May", "_", "N")
("Matt","1"):("Dan", "1", "R")
("May","_"):("May", "1", "L")
```

the out put needs to be

```
 {
    ("Tom","1"):("Tom", "x", "R"),
    ("Tom","_"):("Matt", "_", "L"),
    ("Matt","1"):("Matt", "1", "L"),
    ("Matt","x"):("Dan", "1", "R"),
    ("Matt","_"):("May", "_", "N"),
    ("Matt","1"):("Dan", "1", "R"),
    ("May","_"):("May", "1", "L")
}
```

this how i so far read from the file,

many thanks in advance

Comment: i tryed this transition_data = dict(line.split(':', 2) for line in open('/Users/Desktop/TC/encoding.txt')) but it adds () to each item, i dont what that

Comment: Do you want the keys and values to be tuples or strings looking like tuples (without parentheses)?

Comment: strings looking like tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may offer

```
data = open(...).readlines()
dct = {line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1] for line in data}
```

Comment: this works :) how do you make it so it only reads after skiping 2 rows after reading ? thanks a lot

Comment: At the end of first row add "[2:]" to take only from cell 2 (third) to the end of lines list
`data = open(...).readlines()[2:]
dct = {line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1] for line in data}`

Comment: the out put that i got is {'("q2","_")': '("q4", "_", "N")\n', '("q3","_")': '("q2", "1", "L")', '("q3","1")': '("q3", "1", "R")\n', '("q1","_")': '("q2", "_", "L")\n', '("q1","1")': '("q1", "x", "R")\n', '("q2","x")': '("q3", "1", "R")\n', '("q2","1")': '("q2", "1", "L")\n'} very close this so stores brake line and wrap each of them in '', is there a way to remove both of these, thanks

Comment: Can't understand what happend... My original offer worked for you? Where did the q's come from?

Comment: i tryed it with a diffident data set, but the problem is still there, it adds "\n" to the dictionary and on each of the item it seems to wrap it with  single quotes.This is the Output i get:
{
'("Tom","_")': '("Matt", "_", "L")\n', '("Matt","x")': '("Dan", "1", "R")\n', '("Tom","1")': '("Tom", "x", "R")\n', '("Matt","1")': '("Dan", "1", "R")\n', '("Matt","_")': '("May", "_", "N")\n', '("May","_")': '("May", "1", "L")'
}

Comment: How do you print it? If you just do `print dct` then it may be the problem but don't worry, it is just how it prints, in the memory it is not stored like that. About the '\n', I suggest to use `.read().split("\n")` , not `.readlines()`

Comment: i am just doing normal print(people) , it is the single  quotes that's causing the problem now, i looked at how it is stored as well it does have the ''.

Comment: This is the edited code.
data = open("/Users/Data.txt").read().split("\n")[2:]
peope = {line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1] for line in data}
print(peope )
the \n is fixed , it is just the double single quotes causing the problem

Comment: Try printing in a loop or something
`for k in people.keys():
    print k
for v in people.values():
    print v`

It will print them all (keys then values but it does'nt matter, just showing that the quotes don't really exist

Comment: {('q3', '1'): ('q3', '1', 'R'), ('q2', 'x'): ('q3', '1', 'R'), ('q3', '_'): ('q2', '1', 'L'), ('q2', '_'): ('q4', '_', 'N'), ('q1', '1'): ('q1', 'x', 'R'), ('q2', '1'): ('q2', '1', 'L'), ('q1', '_'): ('q2', '_', 'L')}
--------
{"('q2','1')": "('q2', '1', 'L')", "('q1','1')": "('q1', 'x', 'R')", "('q2','_')": "('q4', '_', 'N')", "('q2','x')": "('q3', '1', 'R')", "('q3','_')": "('q2', '1', 'L')", "('q1','_')": "('q2', '_', 'L')", "('q3','1')": "('q3', '1', 'R')"}
the first one is the way out needs to be out putted, it this is what i get

Comment: it not the printing it is needed for, it used in a function and thats is the structure it takes , i really appreciate your help Neo :)

Comment: When you print simply by `print` it's just how it works - when `print` prints lists or dicts if there are strings in it the strings will be surrounded with quotes